# Не срабатывают условия

Tags: python, циклы, условия

```
num = [1,2,3,4]

print(num)

while True:
    user_try = str(input("Ну давай, отгадай:"))

    bools = 0
    cows = 0

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if i == j:
                if user_try[i] == num[j]:
                    bools = bools + 1
                continue
            if user_try[i] == num[j]:
                cows = cows + 1

    if bools == 4:
        print("Поздравляю, ты победил. Это было число", num)
        break
    else:
        print(bools,"Быков и", cows, "Коров")
```

В любом случае вывод >>>0 быков и 0 коров

Comment: А еще "быки" - это "bulls", но не "bools". Хотя для программиста это нормально. (шутка)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обоих местах нужно заменить

```
if user_try[i] == num[j]: # сравнивается строка с числом, результат всегда False
```

на

```
if user_try[i] == str(num[j]): # сравнивается строка со строкой
```

или на

```
 if int(user_try[i]) == num[j]: # сравнивается число с числом
```